# Using components Angular using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child, angular-components

**Situation:**

- I have a "main page" where we can see books that are in stocks.
- "Main page" and blue box in the picture are the same component.
- I also have a component called "search".

**Wanted result:**

- I would like to use the "Search" comp. (green box) inside "main page".
- I'd like to allow for the user to input information in the search box and display the result in the "main page" (Blue box).

**Question:**

How would one approach this situation? I've read a little about some type pf parent/child solution - but I dont feel as I quite understand how that would work in my case.

[image]

PS. If anyone feels as the question is not accurate enough - you may change it!

Comment: Watch this live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2svnpt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @JacopoSciampi - Greate stuff!

Comment: Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add an output for the search component

```
@Output() search: string;
```

2. You should bind it to the search component template

```
<app-search (search)="searchStr = $event"></app-search>
```

3. You should use searchStr to filter the list (this you can write a function to it - for example by name)

```
get displayList() {
    return this.list.reduce((sum, value) => {
        if (value.name.substring().indexof(this.searchStr.substring()) > -1) {
            sum.push(value);
        }
        return sum;
    }, []);
}
```

4. Now display the list

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of displayList">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this help